# How to find a matrix which corresponds to given linear transformation and a certain basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Define $P_n$ is a set of all polynomials with real coefficients and degree at most $n$:
>
> 1. Show that $P_n$ is a vector space.
> 2. Show that $B=\{1,x, x^2, x^3, \ldots , x^n\}$ is a basis of $P_n$.
> 3. Define $T: P_n \to P_n$ by $T(P(x))=xP'(x)$. Show that $T$ is a linear operator.
> 4. Find the matrix which corresponds to $T$ and $B$.

a. For part (2), how can we say $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots,x^n\}$ are independent? Why does $c_0+c_1x+...+c_nx^n=0$ imply that $c_0=c_1=...=c_n=0$? If $c_i\neq0$, then?

b. How to do part (4)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

Question 2): A (nonzero) polynomial of degree $d$ has at most $d$ roots. Now, if there's a non-trivial linear relation between $1, x,x^2,\dots, x^n$:
$$p(x)=c_0+c_1x+c_2x^2+\dots+c_nx^n=0,$$
this means the polynomial $p(x)$ has *any* real number $\alpha$ as a root. However, if the coefficients are not all zero, $\deg p(x)$ is defined (only the degree of $0$ is not defined), and $\deg p(x)\le n$, so hat it should have a finite number of roots.

Question 4): The column vectors of the matrix are the coordinates of $T(x^k),\  k=0,\dots, n-1\;$ in basis $\mathcal B$.
$$T(x^k)=x\cdot kx^{k-1}=kx^k,$$
hence $$T=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&\dots&0\\
0&1&0&\dots&0\\
0&0&2&\dots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\dots&0\\
0&0&0&\dots&n
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: To show that $c_0+c_1x+...+c_nx^n=0$ for any $x$ implies $c_0=c_1=...=c_n=0$, look at the derivatives.

Comment: Analysis is not required for that: it is true for any field that has at least $n+1$ elements.

Comment: still do not understand about question 2. if x^2+2x+1=0, rot x=-1, and the coefficients are not zero.

Comment: @Matthew: see my updated answer.